# Show that this sequence is absolutely convergent

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $\mathbb{T} = [0,1)$ denote the torus. If $f,f',$ and $f'' $ are continuous over $\mathbb{T}$, then can we conclude that $f \in A(\mathbb{T})$, the space of absolutely convergent Fourier series.

The answer, I think, should be yes. Let $f$ satisfy the requirements above, and we are interested in $\hat{f}$. Then we can write $\hat{f'}(n) = 2 \pi in\hat{f}(n)$. We can also do this for the derivative itself. But how can I use this to show that $\hat{f} \in \ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$?

Thanks :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuity of $f'$ implies that $\hat {f'} \in \ell^{2} (\mathbb Z)$. So $\sum |n\hat f (n)|^{2} <\infty$. Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the fact that $\sum n^{-2} <\infty$ to finish the proof. You don't require continuity of $f''$ for this.

Comment: Why does continuity of $f'$ imply that $\hat{f'}$ is square-summable?

Comment: @AsukaLangleySohryu The Fourier coefficients of any square integrable function belong to $\ell^{2}(\mathbb Z)$.